# How to download products from ESA's scihub using OData protocol?

Tags: sentinel-1, esa

How one can download files programatically using [scihub](https://scihub.esa.int/dhus/) OData protocol and cURL (or other library/program)?

You can get a descriptive xml response of the API for a  dataset can be obtained by this example:

`curl -u username:password "https://scihub.esa.int/dhus/odata/v1/Products('177db57e-56ca-4588-830a-cfb8712ecf6f')/$value/"`

But how you can actually use it to pull actual data ?

Comment: This is good question - I try to figure it out as well, their instructions at https://scihub.esa.int/twiki/do/view/UserGuide/WalkThrough don't work and contact list is empty :-J

Comment: I also contacted them at eosupport@copernicus.esa.int about a week ago. So far no one answered my question. I'm guessing the functionality is not yet ready and therefore the preliminary WalkThrough has not been updated as well.

Comment: The guide seems to be available here: https://scihub.esa.int/twiki/do/view/DhusDemo/DhusWalkThrough

Answer (score 4):

For dowloading the data with their original name, you may use the -JO parameter of curl as in the following example:

```
curl -u username:password -JO "https://scihub.esa.int/dhus/odata/v1/Products('177db57e-56ca-4588-830a-cfb8712ecf6f')/$value
```

If you think about listing the products, you could try the following for ten product from the 20th:

```
curl -u username:password "https://scihub.esa.int/dhus/odata/v1/Products?$skip=19&$top=10"
```

You can get the full data model exposed via the following call:

```
curl -u username:password "https://scihub.esa.int/dhus/odata/v1/$metadata"
```

It should be a good starting point for building the OData URLs and browse the content of a DHuS, download the products, get metadata, quicklook, GML footprint or even get values extracted the product content i.e. file content.

I hope this helps. Do not hesitate for any further information ;)

Comment: Great. Thanks. I am not super familiar with OData, I tried the various URLs you provided but apart from basic metadata such as geometry and start stop time, I couldn't find very much. I am specifically looking for quicklooks, mode, beam/incidence angle, polarisation, etc... I am missing something?

Comment: Hi! Unfortunally curl complains that the remote filename has no lenght. I tried to redirect the output to a file but still refuses. Without the O parameter, the request that comes back from the server is the plain metadata xml.

Comment: @Thomas, the Product properties are generic to cope with virtually any data and in particular the coming Sentinel 2 and 3. You are looking for specific characteristics that you should find as Products/Attributes as in the following example: `https://scihub.esa.int/dhus/odata/v1/Products('177db57e-56ca-4588-830a-cfb8712ecf6f')/Attributes)`
Unfortunately, the current version of the SciHub does not extract any attribute for Sentinel 1 products so the the result set is empty. This should be fixed by next Tuesday, after the planned maintenance cf. [link](https://scihub.esa.int/news/News00011)

Comment: @nickves, are you sure that your URL is well formed and for example does not include spaces? Without O option, you should not receive the metadata.xml. Could you provide us with your complete command line?

Comment: @stephane, thanks for the heads up. I tried and I am getting a "Navigation failed (result is null)". Taking another angle, do you know if it is possible to download the whole archive metadata as files? eg KMLs or Shapefiles.

Comment: @thomas, the following URL is working for me and lists a variety of attributes: `https://scihub.esa.int/dhus/odata/v1/Products('4fcc6058-514e-4f52-87b4-445d0d8029e4')/Attributes`. There is a new documentation on [ESA web site](https://scihub.esa.int/userguide/BatchScripting)

Comment: @Thomas, for getting a product metadata you may consider downloading only the annotation XML files contained in the product. Following URL is a bit long but does the job:

`https://scihub.esa.int/dhus/odata/v1/Products('4fcc6058-514e-4f52-87b4-445d0d8029e4')/Nodes('S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20141205T060219_20141205T060244_003580_00439E_129B.SAFE')/Nodes('annotation')/Nodes('s1a-iw-grd-vh-20141205t060219-20141205t060244-003580-00439e-002.xml')/$value`

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a Python Library and utility to search and download Sentinel data: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sentinelsat

Comment: [Here's a small example](http://fernerkundung.github.io/download-sentinel-images-with-python/) on how to use the [`sentinelsat`](https://github.com/ibamacsr/sentinelsat) package.

Answer (score 1):

The `curl` command didn't work for me as well.
But, there's a `bash` [script](https://scihub.esa.int/twiki/pub/SciHubUserGuide/BatchScripting/odata-demo.sh) which is working quite well. The last option (`12`) allow the `download of a full product` from its `id`.

Run it with `bash odata-demo.sh`, and select the appropriate option `12`.

Note that option `2` related to products from a specific collection is not working, but I guess they're preparing it for the inclusion of `Sentinel-2` data.