# Obtaining Sentinel raster for API

Tags: copernicus, sentinel-hub

I need to download some Sentinel images from scihub-Copernicus to use them on an application.

Does anyone know how to obtain the sentinel raster for a region (I have the polygon coordinates) using cURL or Wget?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190312/downloading-sentinel-products-using-api

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Downloading sentinel products using API?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190312/downloading-sentinel-products-using-api)